# Make sharepoint doesn't show people from specific domain

Tags: people-picker, stsadm

I am very new to SP server and I really don't understand the documentation that much.

So, I am managing the SP server and there are 2 domains("DIR" and "GDNEUROPE.com").
GDNEUROPE must be removed from people picker. How can I do it?

Stsadm is already assigned as system variable on windows server. I think this is the right [command](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c95da957-8eeb-4312-b039-7ac5c0f89a7e(office.12).aspx), but I am not sure! Especially about the URL part(I don't know it's url. I pinged it through console and it gave me the IP, but I am not sure)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll find the solution [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263460(v=office.12).aspx):

Using restriction on AD Forests by Stsadm:

```
stsadm -o setsiteuseraccountdirectorypath -path "OU=Sales,DC=ContosoCorp,DC=local" -url http://ServerName
```

I also prefer to do it in [PowerShell:](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg602075.aspx)

Comment: But the problem is, how can I know GDNEUROPE url.. Actually it is called gdneurope.com. How you think, might this be the correct url? I pinged it, it doesn't receive packages, but it has his own IP

Comment: It's not about url. It's Active Directory.
With this command: stsadm -o setproperty -pn peoplepicker-searchadforests -pv domain:DIR -url webapplicationURL
You should work only with one domain.

Comment: Excuse me for so stupid question! webapplicationURL - is the url of server on which it is installed? could this be ip?

Comment: No, it's the SharePoint webapplication where you want to restrict the domain.

Comment: I found out that protocol for this web application had https protocol not http. Command line that u have given me is executed successfully. But people picker still see accaounts from gdneurope. I only executed one command line. I need to take peopleonly from dir

Comment: I really dont even understand how to google this..

Comment: This what i got from getproperty peoplepicker-searchadforests:
<Property Exist="Yes" Value="domain:dir.svc.hella.com" />

Comment: And when I am talking about 2 domains(I don't know how it is called), in webapp peoplepicker there can be, for example: dir\foo.boo and gdneurope\foo.boo - one person different rules for them. Gdneurope must disappear

Comment: To google this, use keywords such as "peoplepicker sharepoint ..."
I understand what you mean, and normally restriction should be effective as well...

Comment: http://blog.ithinksharepoint.com/2008/10/30/restricting-the-people-picker-to-searching-one-domain/

Comment: Now I am getting this error while trying to change varuble of app:
The server instance specified was not found" error message when you perform an operation on a virtual server in Windows SharePoint Services

Comment: This is very funny task. Cause: ISS is telling me that it is running. And I can actually go to this webapp

Comment: Review the command line you're pushing ... I think you did a mistake somewhere. http/https are important also.

Comment: Hey again! Is "OU" and "CN" parts of the command line is necessarily needed?

Comment: Not necessarily. Just DC could be enough.

Comment: Ok, there is 2 sites: the real one and the training site. The command worked for training environment, but on the 1st one it doesn't work. I guess I need to compare their configurations, somehow